# Count the number of values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe built like:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | A |
| 3 | Nan |

For every value of Col1, I want to count every value of Col2 ignoring the Nan values and put the sum in the associated column, obtaining something like:

| Col1 | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |

How can I do that in Pandas? I have a lot of values in Col1 and lots of columns like Col2.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply do this !!works!!

```
df.groupby(list(df.columns)).size().unstack()
```

output:

```
Col2    A    B
Col1          
1     1.0  2.0
2     2.0  NaN
3     1.0  NaN
```

Comment: I generally prefer using `df.columns.tolist()` instead of `list(df.columns)` - it's more pandas-esque :)

Comment: Noted will do that from now on and will also edit the post.

Answer (score 5):

You can try `crosstab`

```
out = pd.crosstab(df.Col1, df.Col2).reset_index()
Out[66]: 
Col2  Col1  A  B
0        1  1  2
1        2  2  0
2        3  1  0
```

Comment: your answer seems very interesting can you explain your code.

Comment: @M.Twarog Crosstab function below https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the columns and set the values to a new column.

```
sum_column = df["col1"] + df["col2"]
df["col3"] = sum_column
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have several columns and want to count the values over all columns, here's a maybe not too elegant, but working solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                   ["A", "B", "A", "C", "b", "A", "A", "A", np.nan],
                   ["a", "a", "C", "b", "A", "b", "a", "b", np.nan]
                   ]).T
df.columns = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"]

result = {}
for i, group in df.groupby("Col1"):
    result[i] = group.drop(columns=["Col1"]).stack().value_counts()
result = pd.DataFrame(result).T.fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to achieve this(@BENY has already provided the crosstab option):

`pd.get_dummies`:

```py
(pd
.get_dummies(df, columns=["Col2"], prefix="", prefix_sep="")
.groupby("Col1")
.sum()
)
      A  B
Col1      
1     1  2
2     2  0
3     1  0
```

`pivot_table`:

```py
(df.pivot_table(index="Col1", columns="Col2", aggfunc="size", fill_value=0))

Col2  A  B
Col1      
1     1  2
2     2  0
3     1  0
```

`value_counts`:

```py
(df
.value_counts()
.unstack(fill_value=0)
.rename_axis(columns=None)
) 
      A  B
Col1      
1     1  2
2     2  0
3     1  0
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `pandas.pivot_tabel()`. Link is available https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html.

Comment: you must present a relevant solution just mentioning the link of a possible solution is not enough.